What came first: electric potential or electric field?
If we consider the situation where there are two conductors connected via wire, we say the electric potential is distributed evenly. However, we can also say that from knowing that the electric field inside any conductor is $0$ (using the work formula).
So the question is: Is electric potential distributed evenly due to the electric field inside any conductor being $0$ OR the electric field is $0$ because electric potential is distributed evenly inside a conductor?

It resembles the electrostatic variant of the well-known dilemma between chicken and egg.  Actually, in this case, there is no precedence. Potential and field are two equivalent ways of describing the physical situation.

@GiorgioP no the electric field of the conductor is a response to the external electrical potential and like everything it doesnt happen instantenously.Please check out my answer below.Thanks.

Consider that in dynamic systems there is no well defined scalar potential, but there are still electric fields. On the other hand, the Aharanov-Bohm effect implies that the potential has a physical effect independent of the associated field.

@RootGroves It's a basic fact of the Theory of electromagnetism that fields and potentials are two ways to describe the underlying Physics. External potentials or fields are also equivalent ways to fix the boundary conditions. The finite value of the speed of light introduces a delay in the response. But retarded potentials or retarded fields are again inter-related.

@GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 The electric field of the conductor is NOT necessarily in the same phase with the external potential of the conductor because electrons which place themselves at the surface of the conductor have inertia.Im done talking.Im not going to do a Transmission Line Theory 101 here.

Electric potential is not "distributed", the verb does not apply to the noun. What you should say is that potential is constant, or uniform.

@Photon Scalar electric potential is fine and well-defined even in "dynamical systems". Just as vector magnetic potential. One can define them in any situation in classical EM theory, e.g. via the Helmholtz decomposition of electric and magnetic field, or define them based on past state of charges via the Lienard-Wiechert formulae. Or differently, using the Coulomb potential for electric potential, and vector potential in the Coulomb gauge for magnetic vector potential.

Surface charge comes first. The field and the potentials are mathematical quantities that express (in the form of a vector, or in the form of a scalar) how the surface charge is distributed on the surface of the bodies before and after you make the connection.

In general, electric field is not zero in a conductor.
Only in idealized electrostatic situation where no current flows anywhere, and charges are at rest, we expect the electric field to be zero in conductor. This is because otherwise we expect there to be current, and that would mean the situation is not static.
For the assumption of static equilibrium we get zero electric field in conductors, and from that we get the consequence, electric potential that is constant throughout the conductor. Both happen at the same time, but in terms of logic, we argue from the zero current, to zero electric field, to constant potential.

thx for your reply

First comes the electric potential.There is a very small amount of time where the electric field inside the conductor is not 0.Thats the restoration time and it is very important in transmission lines because a transmission line is very big in length and the restoration time introduces a phase shift in the frequency domain between the AC voltage and the current of the transmission line.
